# ServiceStack and entity framework Lazy Loading

Tags: c#, entity-framework, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm migrating our WCF web services to ServiceStack. Supose we have 3 entities. Let them be A, B and C.

- A is father of B.
- A is father of C.

In WCF we would have 3 methods to get A with his children:

```
public List<A> GetAWithBIncluded()
{
    return Repository.A.Include("B").ToList();
}

public List<A> GetAWithCIncluded()
{
    return Repository.A.Include("C").ToList();
}

public List<A> GetAWithBAndCIncluded()
{
    return Repository.A.Include("B").Include("C").ToList();
}
```

I'm having enormous difficult to translate this process to ServiceStack manner. Can you guys provide some examples?

The best I came up with is:

```
public class AResponse
{
    public List<A> As {get;set;}
    ....//One list of each type.
}
```

We know we cannot use WCF with lazyloading, but can ServiceStack and ormlite do the trick of fully automated process of data access without overcharging the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using EF, I would probably do something like this:

```
[Route("/a")]
public class GetAs : IReturn<List<A>>
{
    public bool IncludeB { get; set; }
    public bool IncludeC { get; set; }
}

public class AService : Service
{
    private readonly AContext _aContext;

    public AService(AContext aContext)
    {
        _aContext = aContext;
    }

    public object Get(GetAs req)
    {
        var res = _aContext.As;

        if (req.IncludeB)
            res = res.Include("B");

        if (req.IncludeC)
            res = res.Include("C");

        return res.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Very interesting your approach, I will leave open for now to see more examples.

Comment: Sure! Be interesting to see if others answer, how they'd approach it! :)